# TramineR sequence plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, traminer

I'm new to the TramineR package and would like to use ggplot to create a state distribution plot. The plot below was created with the TramineR package, but how can I extract the data and plot it with ggplot? i would like to change the axis and colours as well?

[image]

Sample code:

```
dev.off()
seqdplot(df_new.seq[1:10,], border=0,
         axes=T, yaxis=T, xaxis=T, ylab="",
         cex.legend=0.5, ncol=6, legend.prop=.11)
```

Sample data:

```
structure(list(`04:00` = structure(c(19L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("PC", 
"SL", "EA", "WR", "ST", "DI", "FP", "FO", "LA", "IR", "HO", "CH", 
"CA", "LE", "CO", "TV", "RA", "TR", "OT", "*", "%"), class = "factor"), 
    `04:10` = structure(c(19L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("PC", "SL", 
    "EA", "WR", "ST", "DI", "FP", "FO", "LA", "IR", "HO", "CH", 
    "CA", "LE", "CO", "TV", "RA", "TR", "OT", "*", "%"), class = "factor"), 
    `04:20` = structure(c(19L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("PC", "SL", 
    "EA", "WR", "ST", "DI", "FP", "FO", "LA", "IR", "HO", "CH", 
    "CA", "LE", "CO", "TV", "RA", "TR", "OT", "*", "%"), class = "factor"), 
    `04:30` = structure(c(19L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("PC", "SL", 
    "EA", "WR", "ST", "DI", "FP", "FO", "LA", "IR", "HO", "CH", 
    "CA", "LE", "CO", "TV", "RA", "TR", "OT", "*", "%"), class = "factor"), 
    `04:40` = structure(c(19L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("PC", "SL", 
    "EA", "WR", "ST", "DI", "FP", "FO", "LA", "IR", "HO", "CH", 
    "CA", "LE", "CO", "TV", "RA", "TR", "OT", "*", "%"), class = "factor"), 
    `04:50` = structure(c(19L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("PC", "SL", 
    "EA", "WR", "ST", "DI", "FP", "FO", "LA", "IR", "HO", "CH", 
    "CA", "LE", "CO", "TV", "RA", "TR", "OT", "*", "%"), class = "factor"), 
    `05:00` = structure(c(19L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("PC", "SL", 
    "EA", "WR", "ST", "DI", "FP", "FO", "LA", "IR", "HO", "CH", 
    "CA", "LE", "CO", "TV", "RA", "TR", "OT", "*", "%"), class = "factor"), 
    `05:10` = structure(c(19L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("PC", "SL", 
    "EA", "WR", "ST", "DI", "FP", "FO", "LA", "IR", "HO", "CH", 
    "CA", "LE", "CO", "TV", "RA", "TR", "OT", "*", "%"), class = "factor"), 
    `05:20` = structure(c(19L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("PC", "SL", 
    "EA", "WR", "ST", "DI", "FP", "FO", "LA", "IR", "HO", "CH", 
    "CA", "LE", "CO", "TV", "RA", "TR", "OT", "*", "%"), class = "factor"), 
    `05:30` = structure(c(19L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("PC", "SL", 
    "EA", "WR", "ST", "DI", "FP", "FO", "LA", "IR", "HO", "CH", 
    "CA", "LE", "CO", "TV", "RA", "TR", "OT", "*", "%"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), start = 1, missing = NA, void = "%", nr = "*", alphabet = c("PC", 
"SL", "EA", "WR", "ST", "DI", "FP", "FO", "LA", "IR", "HO", "CH", 
"CA", "LE", "CO", "TV", "RA", "TR", "OT"), class = c("stslist", 
"data.frame"), labels = c("Personal care", "Sleep", "Eating", 
"Work", "Study", "Dishwash", "Food preparation", "Household upkeep", 
"Laundry", "Ironing", "Housework", "Childcare", "Care for adults", 
"Leisure", "Computing", "TV", "Radio and music", "Travel", "Other"
), cpal = c("#FFB3B5", "#F8B8A2", "#EDBE91", "#DDC485", "#CBCA82", 
"#B5D087", "#9DD594", "#84D8A6", "#6ED9B9", "#61D9CD", "#66D7DF", 
"#7AD3ED", "#96CCF8", "#B3C5FD", "#CEBDFD", "#E3B6F7", "#F3B1EC", 
"#FDAFDC", "#FFB0CA"), missing.color = "darkgrey", xtstep = 19, tick.last = FALSE, Version = "2.2-2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The online help page of `seqplot` (of which `seqdplot` is an alias for `type="d"`) states

> A State distribution plot (type="d") represents the sequence of the
> cross-sectional state frequencies by position (time point) computed by
> the seqstatd function and rendered with the plot.stslist.statd method.
> Such plots are also known as chronograms.

So you get the data used by `seqdplot` with function `seqstatd`. Actually, the distributions are in the attribute `Frequencies`.

Your sample data contains only three sequences of length 10 with a single spell in state 'OT'. I stored it in `s.spl`

```
s.spl
#   Sequence                     
# 1 OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT
# 2 OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT
# 3 OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT-OT
```

The distributions by position are

```
sd <- seqstatd(s.spl)
sd$Frequencies
#    04:00 04:10 04:20 04:30 04:40 04:50 05:00 05:10 05:20 05:30
# PC     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# SL     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# EA     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# WR     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# ST     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# DI     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# FP     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# FO     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# LA     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# IR     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# HO     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# CH     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# CA     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# LE     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# CO     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# TV     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# RA     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# TR     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# OT     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Good luck if want to rewrite `TraMineR`'s plotting facilities with `ggplot`

Answer (score 2):

As @Gilbert pointed out, your example data is not really useful. Therefore, I use the example data attached to `TraMiner` for my answer.

So let's start setting up the data

```
library(TraMineR)  

## biofam data set
data(biofam)
## We use only a sample of 300 cases
set.seed(10)
biofam <- biofam[sample(nrow(biofam),300),]
biofam.lab <- c("Parent", "Left", "Married", "Left+Marr",
                "Child", "Left+Child", "Left+Marr+Child", "Divorced")
biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam, 10:25, labels=biofam.lab)
```

Now let's turn to the actual plot. With `{TraMineR}`'s `seqplot` this is a fairly easy job.

```
# Convenient out of the box TraMineR plot
seqdplot(biofam.seq)
```

[image: Distribution Plot made with seqdplot function]

If you want to use `{ggplot2}` instead, the data have to be reshaped. As indicated by @Gilbert, you first have to extract the state distributions from `seqstatd`. In a second step, you have to reshape the resulting data into a *tidy* format, e.g. by using `pivot_longer`.

```
# Extract and reshape state distributions 
dplotdata <- as_tibble(seqstatd(biofam.seq)$Frequencies,
                       rownames = "state") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -1,
               names_to = "time",
               names_prefix = "a",
               names_transform = list(time = as.integer))

dplotdata

# # A tibble: 128 x 3
# state  time value
# <chr> <int> <dbl>
#   1 0        15 0.987
# 2 0        16 0.95 
# 3 0        17 0.937
# 4 0        18 0.897
# 5 0        19 0.83 
# 6 0        20 0.74 
# 7 0        21 0.63 
# 8 0        22 0.54 
# 9 0        23 0.45 
# 10 0        24 0.373
# # ... with 118 more rows
```

Once this has been accomplished, you can use `{ggplot2}` to recreate the output from `seqdplot`. Note that I had to reverse the order of the fill variable (states) to get the same output as  `seqdplot`. If the stacking order is irrelevant to you, the code could be shortened.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

# Extract color palette from sequence object
cpal <- attributes(biofam.seq)$cpal 

# plot
ggplot(dplotdata, aes(fill = rev(state), y = value, x = time)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           width = 1, colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(cpal),
                    labels = rev(biofam.lab)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(.01,0))) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(add = .15)) +
  labs(x = "", y = glue("Rel. Freq. (n={nrow(biofam.seq)})")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image: Distribution Plot made with ggplot2]

As you see, the ggplot2 solution requires some extra work, which might be well-invested if you are more familiar with `{ggplot2}` than with R's `{base} plot`. Given the convenience of `seqplot` I recommend to always start with those plots before turning to `{ggplot2}`.

---

P.S.: In the meantime, I finished my work on a little R library for rendering sequence plots with `{ggplot2}`. The library is called [`{ggseqplot}`](https://maraab23.github.io/ggseqplot/) and is available on Cran and GitHub.

```
# Use ggseqdplot for producing the figure
install.packages("ggseqplot")
library(ggseqplot)
ggseqdplot(biofam.seq)
```

[image: Basic version of ggseqdplot]
You can change the appearance of the plot just like you do with every other ggplot:

```
ggseqdplot(biofam.seq, border = T) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:16,
                   labels = 15:30) +
  labs(x = "Age") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[image: ggseqdplot after some adjustments]

Comment: Based on the discussion here and on questions raised in my sequence analysis workshops, I drafted a little library that currently allows creating sequence index plots and state distribution plots based on sequence object defined with `TraMineR:seqdef` using `ggplot2` instead of base R's `plot`. The required data manipulation is done automatically. You can find (a very early release of) the library here:  https://github.com/maraab23/ggseqplot